# Why are local variables also called "Automatic" in Java?

Tags: java, variables, local-variables

I read this in Kathy Sierra's book:

"Local variables are sometimes called stack, temporary, automatic, or method
variables, but the rules for these variables are the same regardless of what you
call them."

Why are the local variables called automatic?

Comment: it's also called automatic in C/C++ with the keyword `auto` (not the new auto variable in C++)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Local variables **automatically** cease to exist when the execution of the block in which they are declared completes.

```
 {
   int a = some_initialisation_value;
   ....
 }
 // a automatically vanishes here.
```

Comment: you can not declare just int a; a should be initialized.

Comment: @giri   True UNLESS noone uses this particular var, in which case declaring just int a; is perfectly valid although rather meaningless. I've no intention of splittring hairs here but one of the questions on the OCA exam asked me exactly that.

Answer (score 11):

Good ol' [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable)

> In computer programming, an automatic variable is a lexically-scoped variable which is allocated and de-allocated automatically when program flow enters and leaves the variable's scope. The term local variable is usually synonymous with automatic variable, since these are the same thing in many programming languages.

Comment: (For newbies like me) Tiny *difference* of local variable and automatic variable: The term local variable is **usually synonymous** with automatic variable, since these are the same thing in many programming languages, **but** local is more general – most local variables are automatic local variables, but **static local variables** also exist, notably in C. For a static local variable, the allocation is static (the lifetime is the **entire** program execution), not automatic, **but** it is only in scope during the execution of the function.(from wikipedia)